# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, statistics, moderation

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Mathematics breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                259         85
Users destroyed                                 204          0
Users deleted                                   458          0
Users contacted                                 369          0
User suspensions lifted early                     5          0
User review-bans lifted early                     1          0
User banned from review                          15          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            59     70,701
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               13     26,959
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         49     78,974
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                1      9,586
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 1     58,090
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              524    138,870
Tags merged                                      15          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            11          9
Tag synonyms created                             11          2
Revisions redacted                                1          0
Questions unprotected                             2         11
Questions reopened                              138        926
Questions protected                              15        211
Questions migrated                               68         73
Questions merged                                 49          0
Questions flagged⁴                               32     21,635
Questions closed                              1,954     36,414
Question flags handled⁴                       3,750     17,917
Posts unlocked                                   37        144
Posts undeleted                                 337     11,010
Posts locked                                    199        443
Posts deleted⁵                                2,724     93,573
Posts bumped                                      0      8,732
Escalations to the CM team                       58          0
Comments undeleted                              226          0
Comments flagged                                266     41,450
Comments deleted⁶                            26,730    122,310
Comment flags handled                        13,884     27,832
Bounties canceled                                 9          0
Answers flagged                                  88     12,489
Answer flags handled                          4,769      7,808
All comments on a post moved to chat             98          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Thanks for the data and happy new year to you as well. Also, thank you to all the users that help moderate the site!

Comment: "Users destroyed" O_o

Comment: Since Aloizio and myself have been moderators only a third of the year, how do our actions before and after August 14 are counted?

Comment: Before August 14th, I count your actions in column #3; actions taken after you were elected go into column #2, @Asaf. Same in reverse for any actions Mariano might've taken.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'm perplexed by the category: "Users destroyed", in contrast to "Users deleted."  What differentiates a "user detroyed" from a "user deleted"?  Just curious.

Comment: Destroy == troll/spammer, @amWhy. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user

Comment: Ahh, thanks, @Shog9.  Happy New Year!

Comment: @Shog9: One more question: do you have any information on the number of "sock puppet" accounts deleted this past year? (No doubt  this falls under the Moderator column), and the number of accounts/users deleted overall includes those deleted as "sock-puppet accounts".)  So I'm just wondering if there is any finer data about # of deleted users in each of the "reasons why an account/user is deleted."

Comment: I do have this information, but it's a bit of a pain to retrieve. [Here are the broad strokes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312390/do-we-lose-users-users-voluntarily-deleting-their-account/312397#312397); post a separate request if you'd like me to dig deeper, @amWhy - if enough others are interested, I can put the time in.

Comment: Thanks, @Shog9 !