# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, statistics, moderation

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Mathematics over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 204        124
Users destroyed³                                 199          0
Users deleted                                    313          0
Users contacted                                  304          0
User suspensions lifted early                      4          0
User review-bans lifted early                      4          0
User banned from review                           62          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue             55     63,685
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                 8     23,345
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue          29     63,404
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue                 1      8,845
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                  7     53,793
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue               988    113,993
Tags merged                                       30          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             18          2
Tag synonyms created                              18          2
Questions unprotected                              0          8
Questions reopened                                86      1,009
Questions protected                               12        122
Questions migrated                                31         64
Questions merged                                 120          0
Questions flagged⁵                                19     17,535
Questions closed                               1,611     32,551
Question flags handled⁵                        2,498     15,095
Posts unlocked                                    21         76
Posts undeleted                                  272     10,685
Posts locked                                     173        366
Posts deleted⁶                                 1,769     84,892
Posts bumped                                       0      8,607
Escalations to the Community Manager team         46          0
Comments undeleted                               200          0
Comments flagged                                 144     10,321
Comments deleted⁷                             17,139     95,757
Comment flags handled                          7,829      2,653
Bounties canceled                                  6          0
Answers flagged                                  132     11,198
Answer flags handled                           3,394      7,941
All comments on a post moved to chat             221          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Since we are starting to close in on a decade of Math.SE, can we also have statistics on a macro scale over the years?

Comment: You don't want to wait for July, @Asaf?

Comment: Oh, that's fine. I'm just recording this idea...

Comment: @Shog9: Can we asked for our account to be destroyed?

Comment: You can ask, but it probably won't happen. In fact, the system would block it entirely even if someone wanted to comply.