# Are there often serial upvoters on the site?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, serial-voting

I started  working on Mathematics Stack Exchange more than $8$ years ago and I had a few problems with serial downvoters.

Starting two days ago, I started facing the opposite situation: a serial upvoter.

Is this frequent? I suppose that the user has been identified since moderators took action to correct the situation. The problem is that I would not like to face similar situations again. Is there any remedy?

Comment: In what way were their up-votes "serial"? Were they targeted at you, or someone else? Did they dig up someone's old questions and give them up-votes in rapid succession, or something else?

Comment: It seems [that is the case](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici?tab=reputation). Because it is so blatant the reversal of votes will be handled by the system. For more specific requests you will need to contact a moderator such as in [Math Mods' Office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) or flagging one of your targeted posts for moderators to investigate.

Comment: @TheoBendit. I saw twice in a very short time ten (or about) of my questions/answers upvotes. Twice almost +200 points. !

Comment: Wow! I guess you have something of a fan there. :) Still, when you're up-voting 10 times within 120 seconds, you can't possibly have given your decisions proper weight, so it's voting abuse. I notice it's already been corrected.

Comment: It happened once to me after I had accused someone of plagiarism. Shortly afterwards, I had 30 upvotes and that person accused me of irregularities. So it appeared to be a strange form of revenge. All is reverted now. – I don't like it because it gives a bad impression in the reputation tab, but I doubt that one can do much about it.

Comment: @MartinR. To be strange, it is ! Do you know if the upvoter had been noticed that this is to be avoided ? And what happens ? Cheers :-)

Comment: That account was *deleted* shortly afterwards. As a mere mortal (aka non-moderator) I cannot see if it was self-deleted or by moderators.

Comment: @MartinR. I enjoy the  *"mere mortal (aka non-moderator)"*

Comment: Related on the Main Meta: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/196432). From the answer: *“In no way should you be concerned with reversal statements in yours or anyone else's reputation history.”*

Comment: Often a serial upvoter is not a fan; if new, remember it could also be a new user.  As @MartinR notes that blatant upvoting at times is not complimentary.  It plays with the target's emotions.  Mods can look into it, and/or escalate to CMs, if the script doesn't auto reverse them; but there really is no way to prevent this; if you suspect a bunch of upvotes "too good to be true", expect them to be reversed.  If they are not, you'll need to flag for moderator attention.  But typically, don't use meta, nor speculate on who? or why?

Comment: Also, consider yourself lucky, given your eight years, that you became a "newbie" to receiving serial upvotes.  There's no point in trying to pin down "motive", whether they were nefarious votes, or someone with a crush on you answers ;D

Comment: It's funny that you bring this up today, because today I was serially upvoted too.

Comment: I've had this occur to me in the past but it was reverted by the time I noticed.

Comment: This is continuing ! What can I do to stop it ?

Comment: I also just received -$40$ reputation due to serial voting.

Comment: Weirdly, I recently lost 10 reputation due to serial up-voting. I know that the specific mechanisms are sensibly kept secret, but I'm suddenly super curious how the system detects one single, isolated "serial" upvote!

Comment: In my early days on the site--this is probably a decade ago already--I received, in quick succession, a bunch of upvotes on some of my not-so-recent posts. A few days later I received another burst of upvotes, mostly on the same old posts. This kept repeating, with the set of upvoted posts gradually shifting, but still having lots of overlap with previous upvote bursts. No script ever reversed the upvotes. I did flag the situation for moderator attention, but I remember the flag being declined.

Comment: @TheoBendit I also get a single, isolate voting correction of -10 a few days ago. My wild guess is when the system discover someone is serial upvoting, it undo every votes in that batch of upvotes, even for votes  to multiple users...

Comment: There are also serial *un*-upvoters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is this frequent?

The yearly moderation report (e.g. [2020: a year in moderation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33035/2020-a-year-in-moderation)) does not contain that information. I don't know if a count of voting corrections is kept somewhere, perhaps a moderator can provide more information.

> The problem is that I would not like to face similar situations again.

I understand that. I don't like a “Voting corrected” entry in my reputation tab either because it *may* give the impression to other people that there is something fishy about how I got my reputation.

> Is there any remedy?

I doubt that much can be done about it.

It happened once or twice to me that a user told me that they had upvoted several of my answers as an “extra thank you” for my help. In that case I replied with a comment that this is a bad idea, and explained why.

In any case, the system does not hold it against you. From [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/196432) on the Main Meta:

> **Should I be concerned about reversal statements on my profile?**
>
> No, not at all. It's only an indication of reputation change. After
> all, we can't control the actions of other users. It's very rare where
> we'd run across a user who was committing the voting fraud themselves
> on their own account, and if we believe you're doing that, you will
> have already been warned separately or suspended. In no way should you
> be concerned with reversal statements in yours or anyone else's
> reputation history.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer  and previous comments. o increase your reputation, I upvote and accept your answer !!!! Good joke ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Do you think that it could be possible to ask upvoters to explain why they did it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Only if you know who they are – which is usually not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Last year, someone had upvoted lots of my posts serially. 1-2 days later, I noticed my reputation had automatically decreased (for serial voting).

So my opinion is there is serial upvoter and downvoter. But serial voting is never helpful.

(I had deleted lots of my account so I have some idea of it)