# Educating mass voters

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Over the past two weeks or so, someone(s) have been searching out my answers which they liked, and upvoting them, say $10$ questions or so, but an automated process reverses the votes. I don't know who the person(s) voting are, but do voters know that if they upvote someone's old answers too rapidly, their votes are nullified?

I myself learnt a lot by going through and upvoting old answers of luminaries whose answers I liked, but  never knew that I couldn't upvote too quickly.

The marks don't matter but the deletion leaves an impression as if something shady is going on.

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34284/42969

Comment: And from  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857: *“In no way should you be concerned with reversal statements in yours or anyone else's reputation history.”*

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks, I didn't know that this issue has been discussed here.

Comment: Just to add anecdotes... I've had a bizarre experience recently. I'm not much underway in MSE, and sometimes are periods where I find nothing interesting, and voting positive (or seldom negatively) is rare - well, as I thought. Recently, when I voted one there occured a reminder: "please also vote questions not only answers." Upps? Ok, maybe they're right, mostly I get inspired by answers, so maybe I should do a bit for the askers. So maybe I finally spread some votes to questions, and maybe a couple of answer more than occasionally one or two in a week of lurking... (cntd)

Comment: (...) Crazy, a couple of days after I received an "accept" and 2 votes myself, where one vote has been removed by the bot, saying something like *"1 vote removed due to serial voting"*... I've never seen such a msg in the 14 years here - but of course it looks as, say, the bot is on ecstasy... Well, I'm not much interested in the voting anyway (I had a job getting my "votes" satisfyingly as well with my wife and some friends) so I don't really care. Only when I see, that some people here (like you) are (possibly) suffering on this I only can shake my head about the patterns in MSE...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: *“1 vote removed due to serial voting"* – that can also be because of this [cleanup action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379788/196432)

Comment: @MartinR - ah, nice information, interesting read. Thanks!